# Skin directive doesn't work in WYSIWYG editor when using custom template

Tags: admin, wysiwyg, skin

I'd like to insert images from the *theme folder* to a static block, but the image URL looks to be invalid in the WYSIWYG editor.

```
<p><a href="#"><img alt="" src="{{skin url='images/banners/shopping_banner.jpg}}" /></a></p>
```

The image properly loads in the *front end*, so we can say it works, but I'd like to know how to make these images accessible from the TinyMCE as well.

The interesting part is that if I change the package and theme to default/default, the skin directive looks to work pretty well.

Is something misconfigured (or not configured) in the custom theme XMLs?

---

Or is it the normal behaviour, and I should see only a placeholder image like this in TinyMCE when using {{skin url...}}?

[image]

Anyway, nor this placeholder image is not loaded in admin TinyMCE when using the custom theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is actually normal behaviour. If you want the pics to show in TinyMCE you will have to use the full url path for the image and it will show.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you have maybe idea, how to make at least the placeholder image work in the custom theme? Now there's only a missing img icon on it's place in the TinyMCE; though it loads when using the default theme.